# My dropdown menu doesn't appear using jQuery. Any tips?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to design a dropdown menu. I started to design with just css and this worked well. Then I added jQuery and it worked but a bit glitchy. The slide up animation works fine, and sometimes the slide down too. So I decided to delete the css "animation" and just want to have the jQuery part but now the menu doesn't slide down if I hover over my "Aufgaben".

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,100italic,300italic");

html, body {
    background: #1c1d26;
}

#header {
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#header img {
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

#header nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#header nav ul {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
#header nav ul li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
#header nav ul li a{
    color: black;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header nav a:hover{
    color: red;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
#header nav ul li ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.7;;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}
#header nav ul li ul li {
    width: 150px;
}
#header nav ul li ul li a{
    padding: 3px 14px;
    color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <title>Wilkommen</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dropdown").mouseenter(function () { 
            $("#dropdownchild").children().slideDown('fast');
        });
        $("#dropdown").mouseleave(function () { 
            $("#dropdownchild").children().slideUp('fast');
        });
    });</script>
<body>
        <!--Kopfzeile mit Navigation-->
        <header id="header">
            <img id="logo" src="images/damnik_logo.png" alt="logo">

            <nav id="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="dropdown" href="#">Aufgaben</a>
                        <ul id="dropdownchild">
                            <li><a href="#">HTML Brief</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Erste Website</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tabellen</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Raster Layout</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bericht</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery code is working but there is `display:none` property on `#header nav ul li ul` that's why it is not visible.
Given below is the correct code.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dropdown").mouseenter(function () { 
            $("#dropdownchild").show().children().slideDown('fast');
        });
        $("#dropdown").mouseleave(function () { 
            $("#dropdownchild").hide().children().slideUp('fast');
        });
    });</script>
```

Comment: thank you :) that works. But u have now any tipp for me how the animation will be smooth ? 
i change $("#dropdown").mouseleave to $("#dropdownchild").mouseleave so the menu just disapear if i leave the menu and not just by leave the "Aufgaben".
But at the first enter it shows instantly and disapear instantly. Just by the second move over is appear smooth but disapear do it allways hardly.

And what i need to do for that the menu just disapear then i leave the menu it self or if i leave "aufgaben" but with a little delay ?

Comment: Can you make a codepen? That would be easier to edit.